# Piping and Instrumentation diagram symbols for Position valves and HPLC pumps

Tags: pi-diagram

I'm looking for advice on how to depict the HPLC pump on the P&I Diagram. What is the symbol (or combination of symbols) to indicate that it has 4 switchable inputs and one combined output with the built-in high-pressure pump? (+ *in-situ* flow indicator)

Additionally, I'm looking for the symbol of the position switch valve. It's the thing like this:

[image]'

Have several inputs, out of which only one can be selected, and permanently attached the common output.

Comment: what's the operating principle of the pump? What does switchblade mean in this context? Is it the process connector of the pipe?

Comment: What does the manufacturer show as a symbol? They usually have some example diagrams. Some manufacturers have a whole series of books about the theory - Mannesman Rexroth Sigma for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPLC manufacturer Pharmacia (now Cytiva) draws the pumps and injection valves in their AKTA systems like this. FPLC is a low-pressure HPLC. It sounds like you want the symbol for the injection valve, rather than the pump itself?
[image]

https://btiscience.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/FPLC_Optional_Config.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the attached document. The diagram you showed is not precisely what I needed, but the document contains the needed info in section 7.1.